# Why are variables renamed within a for each statements?

Tags: php

I have wondered for a while now, what the reason is behind the renaming of a variable for a foreach statement. So for example, why is this:

```
foreach ($Foobar as $Foo) {};
```

Not used like this:

```
foreach ($Foobar) {};
```

I understand that this would just check to see if the value was true and is therefore a bad example, yet that doesn't explain why the whole variable needs to be renamed?

Comment: it's not renamed, its another copy of each value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you don't rename the variable, you declare another variable where the `foreach` result on every loop is stored in.

as a example you have this array

```
array('key' => 'value', 'foo' => 'bar');
```

and use this foreach syntax

```
foreach ($Foobar as $value)
```

the variable `$value` hold the value from the current loop of the array.

output each loop

- first loop => $value holds `value`
- second loop => $value holds `bar`

or your can write it like this

```
foreach ($Foobar as $key =>  $value)
```

with this on each loop the array key and value are written in `$key` and `$value`

output each loop

- first loop => $value holds `value` / $key hold `key`
- second loop => $value holds `bar` / $key hold `foo`

Comment: Okay thank you. It has cleared it up for me a lot now. I have been suing them through uni etc and never understood how it was actually working. Made me feel a bit dumb now! Thanks again

Comment: perfect if you now got the point :) may accept this as your answer is this was you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

$Foo is one item of the $Foobar array, not the same variable.

Comment: Oh okay, so the $Foobar array is split into its individual $foo variables?

Answer (score 0):

**$Foo is a variable that contains one different element of the Array $Foobar in each iteration**